# How to send data from fragment to Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, kotlin, bundle

In my application i want use `Fragment` and `Activity` and i want `startActivity` from this `fragment` and i should send data with `startActivity`
I write below codes, but when running application show **null** in `activity`!
**Fragment codes :**

```
homeDashboard_giftInfoLayout.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), DashboardChargeWalletActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(USER_WALLET_PRICE, response.user.wallet.credit)
    intent.putExtra(USER_CHARGED_VALUE, 0)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

**Activity codes :**

```
userWallet = intent?.getStringExtra(USER_WALLET_PRICE).toString()
userWallet.let {
    //User wallet
    dashboardChargeWallet_userWallet.text =
        "${getString(R.string.walletInventory)}: $userWallet ${getString(R.string.toman)}"
}
```

when click on button for `startActivity` i show this `response.user.wallet.credit` into **toast**.
But into `activity` show me **null** !

I used **Kotlin** for language.

How can i fix it?

Comment: you got `userWallet` as null?

Comment: yes dear, show me null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

```
intent.putExtra(USER_WALLET_PRICE, response.user.wallet.credit)
```

I suspect that `response.user.wallet.credit` isn't a string. So the below line:

```
userWallet = intent?.getStringExtra(USER_WALLET_PRICE).toString()
```

won't find a string extra with `USER_WALLET_PRICE` key. Check what type response.user.wallet.credit is, int? long? serializable? and make sure you get it by the same type

Answer (score 1):

you need to use intent like this from a fragment.

```
homeDashboard_giftInfoLayout.setOnClickListener {
 val intent = Intent(activity, DashboardChargeWalletActivity::class.java)
 intent.putExtra(USER_WALLET_PRICE, response.user.wallet.credit)
 intent.putExtra(USER_CHARGED_VALUE, 0)
 startActivity(intent);
}
```

also you can use requireActivity

```
val intent=Intent(requireActivity(),DashboardChargeWalletActivity::class.java)
```

Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: is your response.user.wallet.credit variable in a string and try to check it is not null while passing just to be sure :)

Comment: i check it, show me value of response.user.wallet.credit into log. but when send show me null in activity!

Comment: when remove **?** from `intent?.getStringExtra(USER_WALLET_PRICE).toString()`  show me nullPointerError for **`intent`** !!!

Comment: okay well try to get this value in a different variable like this `val credit = response.user.wallet.credit` if that's not null, try to check that your extra is not null 
`Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String userName;

if (extras != null) {
    userName = extras.getString("name");
    // and get whatever type user account id is
}`

Answer (score 0):

try this, it may help

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoadActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(USER_WALLET_PRICE, response.user.wallet.credit)
    intent.putExtra(USER_CHARGED_VALUE, 0)
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin: Data send fragment to activity**
*step by step follow*

**step 1: fragment side create interface**

```
class SurveyPageOneFragment : Fragment() {
private var _binding: FragmentSurveyPageOneBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
private var mContext: Context? = null

interface OnDataPassFragOne {
    fun onDataPassFragOne(
        firstName : String?,
        middleName : String?,
        lastName : String?,
        mobile: String?,
        age: Int?,
        dob: String?,
        bDay: String?,
        bMonth: String?,
        bYear: String?,
        gender: String?, bloodGroup: String?)
}

private lateinit var dataPasser: OnDataPassFragOne
fun setListener(dataPasser1: OnDataPassFragOne){
    dataPasser = dataPasser1
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    dataPasser = context as OnDataPassFragOne
}

fun passDataFragOne(){
    dataPasser.onDataPassFragOne(firstName,middleName,lastName,mobile,niceAge,birthDate,bDay,bMonth,bYear,gender,bloodGroup)
}}
```

**step 2: go to activity and first changes in setup view pager**

```
 private fun setUpViewPager() {

    surveyPageOneFragment = SurveyPageOneFragment.newInstance(false)
    surveyPageOneFragment.setListener(this)

    surveyPageTwoFragment = SurveyPageTwoFragment.newInstance(false)
    surveyPageTwoFragment.setListenerTwo(this)

    surveyPageThreeFragment = SurveyPageThreeFragment.newInstance(false)
    surveyPageThreeFragment.setListenerThree(this)

    surveyPageFourFragment = SurveyPageFourFragment.newInstance(false)
    surveyPageFourFragment.setListenerFour(this)

    surveyPageFiveFragment = SurveyPageFiveFragment.newInstance(false)
    surveyPageFiveFragment.setListenerFive(this)

    val fragmentList: MutableList<Fragment> = mutableListOf()
    fragmentList.add(surveyPageOneFragment)
    fragmentList.add(surveyPageTwoFragment)
    fragmentList.add(surveyPageThreeFragment)
    fragmentList.add(surveyPageFourFragment)
    fragmentList.add(surveyPageFiveFragment)

    surveyPagerAdapter = SurveyPagerAdapter(fragmentList, supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
    binding.viewPager.adapter = surveyPagerAdapter
    binding.dotsIndicator.attachTo(binding.viewPager)

}
```

**step 3 : In activity call interface**

```
class SurveyInfoActivity : AppCompatActivity() SurveyPageOneFragment.OnDataPassFragOne{

private lateinit var surveyPageOneFragment: SurveyPageOneFragment

override fun onDataPassFragOne(
    firstName: String?,
    middleName: String?,
    lastName: String?,
    mobile: String?,
    age: Int?,
    dob: String?,
    bDay: String?,
    bMonth: String?,
    bYear: String?,
    gender: String?,
    bloodGroup: String?
) {
    Log.i(
        "TAG",
        "fullName: $firstName $middleName $lastName, moble: $mobile, age: $age, dob: $dob, gender: $gender, bloodGroup: $bloodGroup"
    )
    surveyRequestModel.name = "$firstName $middleName $lastName"
    surveyRequestModel.mobileNumber = "$mobile"
    surveyRequestModel.age = "$age"
    surveyRequestModel.dateOfBirth = "$bYear-$bMonth-$bDay"
    surveyRequestModel.gender = "$gender"
    surveyRequestModel.bloodGroup = "$bloodGroup"
}}
```

**step 4: set on click page according to position**

```
binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener {
if (binding.viewPager.currentItem < binding.viewPager.adapter?.itemCount!!) {
    when (fragPosition) {
        0 -> {
            Log.i("TAG", "Page 1: Position $fragPosition")
            binding.viewPager.currentItem = binding.viewPager.currentItem + 1
            surveyPageOneFragment.passDataFragOne()
            saveSurveyFragOne()
        }
    }
}}
```